# Rails, Nested Form, allow one only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, belongs-to

I use nested_form with a model that belongs to another model. Is it possible to nested form only to allow one "new" of the parent object?

Like

**Models**

```
Class Part
  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end

Class Company
  has_many :parts
end
```

**View**

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :company %>
<%= f.link_to_add :company, :class => 'button small' do %>
  Add company
<% end %>
```

Ie I don't want a user to be able to create multiple companies on one part. Just one.

Comment: you can try disabling the link via javascript once the new was clicked, is there a solution for you ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty easy to use some jQuery to hide the Add button. Just give your link_to_add an id (such as hideAfterClick) and do something like this:

```
$("#hideAfterClick").on('click', function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```